# Why are $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ examples for root test tells no information when $\lim\sup|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation, proof-explanation

Why are $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ examples for root test tells no information when $\lim\sup|a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$?

First, we know that $\lim\sup|\frac1n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim\sup|\frac{1}{n^2}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=1$ because $\lim|\frac1n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim (n^{\frac{1}{n}})^{-1}=1$ and $\lim|\frac{1}{n^2}|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim (\frac1n^{\frac{1}{n}})^2=1$, correct?

Second, how do we know that $\sum\frac1n$ converges and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges?

Comment: Do you know the Integral Test for series convergence?  You can compare the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ to the integrals $\int \frac{dx}{x}$, resp. $\int \frac{dx}{x^2}$  Also note that $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges which seems to be what you intended.

Comment: @CoolKid: Did you learn a statement of the root test different from, "If $\limsup |a_{n}|^{1/n} < 1$ then $\sum_{n} a_{n}$ converges absolutely, and if $\limsup |a_{n}|^{1/n} > 1$ then $\sum_{n} a_{n}$ diverges"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, because $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+...+\frac{1}{n}\\ \ge 1+\frac{1}{2}+\left( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left( \frac{1}{5}+...+\frac{1}{8} \right)+...+\left( \frac{1}{2^{m-1}+1}+...+\frac{1}{2^m} \right)\\ \ge 1+\frac{1}{2}+2\cdot\frac{1}{4}+4\cdot\frac{1}{8}+...+2^{m-1}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\\ =1+\frac{m}{2}\rightarrow\infty\\$
$\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, because $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\le 1+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=1+lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}[-\frac{1}{x}]_{1}^{s}=1+lim_{s\rightarrow\infty}\left(-\frac{1}{s}+1\right)=1+1=2$

Answer (score 1):

If $a_n = n^{-p}$, then $\log |a_n|^{1/n} = -p \frac{\log n}{n} \to 0$ for any value of $p$. So, $|a_n|^{1/n} \to 1$. So, you can't really tell any $p$-series's convergence from the root test -- you need some exponential-ish behavior so that the $1/n$ doesn't kill off the information in the size of $a_n$.

Not all tests work in all cases. For example, the integral test would show you that the harmonic series diverges, but $\sum_n n^{-2}$ converges.